# Trying to find a novel where genetic engineering leads to the deaths of a whole 'batch' of children with a particular trait

Tags: story-identification, genetic-engineering

I'm trying to find out the title of a book or short story which I can very dimly remember, no idea on date of publication or even the main plotline! If anyone can identify it from what I can remember, it will be a miracle.

One of the characters was an un-altered female(?) child(?) who was shunned because she was ugly, which basically meant that she hadn't been designed to be perfect like all the others. At some point, a whole batch of children who had been altered to have a particular trait suddenly started dying as the trait had a deadly side effect.

I don't even think that this was the main plot, it may have been a side plot or part of the initial scene setting at the start.

Comment: This sounds like the basic plot of Gattaca, but that was a guy.

Comment: and some of the elements sound like Dark Angel series

Comment: Definitely not Gattaca as it was a book not a film, and I'm almost certain the character was female and was a child when introduced to the reader.

Comment: Did she take part in a school play and get cast as the old woman because, well, y'know? And at the end, when she's at home and the news comes on that all the children with a certain genetic upgrade are falling into comas and dying, her mother (who chose not to let her be engineered) is spitefully *glad*?

Comment: I would very much like to know what this story is definitively.

Comment: Could it be one of the stories on the Union side of [Cherryh's Alliance-Union universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._J._Cherryh_bibliography#The_Alliance-Union_universe)? They have genetically engineered children, lots of female heroes, but I don't remember this particular plot point (I haven't read all the books).

Comment: @Anne: It would be very helpful in identifying this to have some idea of how long ago you read the book.

Comment: If you could maybe provide the year you read this book it'd make it quite a bit easier for us to find the appropriate answer. Until then it's just guessing in it's purest form.

Comment: I've read a very similar short story online somewhere - in that story, the female protagonist was high school age, child of some "hippie" parents. The defect that afefcted an entire generation of children manifested at a particular age, throwing a scare into younger children and their parents. I wonder if this was the same story ...

Comment: This sounds annoyingly familiar to me as well. Did the unaltered, possibly female child have an altered sister?

Comment: Read the story (short story or novellette) in Asimov's Science Fiction in the 90's, IIRC. Young girl is shunned by, then befriended by one of the enhanced children, before they begin to die.

Answer (score 14):

The story you are looking for is ["*Sisters*"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40939) by Greg Bear, which you can find in "Tangents" (a short story collection).

It's a freaking awesome story!

> Of the seven hundred adolescents in her high school training programs, Letitia Blakely was one of ten NGs -- possessors of natural, unaltered genomes. Everyone else was the proud bearer of juggled genes, PPCs or Pre-Planned Children, all lovely and stable  [...]

and later...

> It was not a plague.
> Across the nation, two million children became ill. One million died.
> Letitia read, without really absorbing the truth all at once, that it was the worst disaster in the history of the United States. Riots destroyed PPC centers. Women carrying PPC babies demanded abortions. The Rifkin Society became a political force of considerable influence.

[image: Cover picture]

Comment: Bear said, "Fortunately, this story preceded the excellent film *Gattaca*, which I highly recommend." --The Collected Stories of Greg Bear

Comment: Added the cover from one printing of it; feel free to roll back if you don't approve.  That being said, [here](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/ERBAEN0036/ERBAEN0036___1.htm) is a free online copy (legit) to read to verify if it's the right story :)

Comment: Baen EBook seems to have moved to http://www.baen.com/Chapters/ERBAEN0036/ERBAEN0036.htm

Answer (score 4):

It sounds a bit like Scott Westerfeld's Uglies series. In the books, all kids are surgically modified to be beautiful. When they get the operation, they are also given brain lesions, to make them peaceful and compliant. The books are [*Uglies*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uglies), [*Pretties*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretties), [*Specials*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28novel%29), and [*Extras*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extras_%28novel%29).

Comment: But there is no *"a whole batch of children who had been altered to have a particular trait suddenly started dying as the trait had a deadly side effect."*, at least not in first three books I have read (from what I remember).